# How to use q as exit in bash script menu?

Tags: bash

I use following script:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Menu Runner
# ---------------
function menuShow(){
PS3='Please enter choice: '
opts=("opt1" 
      "opt2" 
      "opt3"
      "Quit")
select opt in "${opts[@]}"
do
    case $opt in
        "opt1")
            echo "option 1"
            ;;
        "opt2")
            echo "option 2"
            ;;
        "opt3")
            echo "option 3"
            ;;
        "Quit")
            break
            ;;
            *) echo "invalid option $REPLY";;
    esac
    pause 'Press [Enter] key to continue...'
done
}

function pause(){
read -p "$*"
}

menuShow
```

My question is:

- How to change quit option so instead of selecting number 4 user must select q
- Is there any other way to number the options statically instead of using auto numbers from opts=()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have more control over the options by using `read`:

```sh
read -p "Choose (1,2,3,q):" -N 1 REPLY
```

Explanation:

- `-p "Choose blablabla"`: the text to display when asking for input
- `-N 1`: get one character, then exit the `read` command to process it
- `REPLY`: the variable where the character typed will be stored

This is an example of how you use it (it will keep asking until the user choses `q` as in your code):

```sh
LOOP=1
while [ "$LOOP" != "0" ]; do
    read -p "Choose (1,2,3,q):" -N 1 REPLY
    echo ""
    case $REPLY in
        "1")
            echo "option 1"
            LOOP=1
            ;;
        "2")

            echo "option 2"
            LOOP=1
            ;;
        "3")
            echo "option 3"
            LOOP=1
            ;;
        "q")
            LOOP=0
            break
            ;;
        *) echo "invalid option $REPLY";;
    esac
done
```

Answer (score 0):

From the *bash man-page*:

> If  theline  consists  of  a  number  corresponding to one of the displayed words, then the value of name is set to that word.  If the line is empty, the words and  prompt  are     displayed  again.   If  EOF  is  read,  the command completes.  Any other value read        causes name to be set to null.  The **line read is saved** in the variable  REPLY.

Hence, if the user enters *q*, `opt` is set to the empty string and the variable `REPLY` is set to the string *q*. You can test this explicitly before entering your `case`....`esac`.

Answer (score 0):

The below code has been tested working on bash 4.4.20

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
array=(item1 item2 item3)

select opt in ${array[@]}; do
    case $opt in
        item1)
            echo "$opt selected!"
            ;;
        item2|item3)
            echo "$opt selected!"
            ;;
        *)
            if [ $REPLY == "q" ]; then
                echo "Quiting..."
                break
            fi
            echo "Invalid option!"
      esac
done

echo "Bye..."
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).